# PostgreSQL Not Recognizing NULL Values

Tags: postgresql

A table in my database (PostgreSQL 9.6) has a mixture of NULL and not null values, which I need to COALESCE() as a part of the creation of another attribute during insert into a resulting dimension table. However, Postgres seems unable to recognize the NULL values as NULL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, description 
FROM my_table 
WHERE name IN('STUDIO', 'ONE BEDROOM') 
 AND description IS NOT NULL;
```

returns

| name | description |
| --- | --- |
| STUDIO | *NULL* |
| ONE BEDROOM | *NULL* |

Whereas

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, description 
FROM my_table 
WHERE name IN('STUDIO', 'ONE BEDROOM') 
 AND description IS NULL;
```

returns

| name | description |
| --- | --- |

as such, something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, COALESCE(description, 'N/A') 
FROM my_table 
WHERE name IN('STUDIO', 'ONE BEDROOM');
```

will return

| name | coalesce |
| --- | --- |
| STUDIO | *NULL* |
| ONE BEDROOM | *NULL* |

instead of the expected

| name | coalesce |
| --- | --- |
| STUDIO | N/A |
| ONE BEDROOM | N/A |

The DDL for these attributes is fairly straightforward:

```
...
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
...
```

I've already checked whether the attribute was filled with 'NULL' rather than being an actual NULL value, and that's not the case. I've also tried quoting the attribute in question as "description" and that hasn't made a difference. Casting to VARCHAR hasn't helped (I thought it might be the fact that it's a TEXT attribute). If I nullify some values in the other text column (name) I'm able to coalesce with a test value, so that one is seemingly behaving as expected leading me to think it's not a data type issue. This table exists in multiple databases on multiple servers and exhibits the same behavior in all of them.

I've tried inserting into a new table that has different attribute definitions:

```
...

    floorplan_name "character varying(128)" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown'::character varying,
    floorplan_desc "character varying(256)" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Not Provided'::character varying,
...
```

resulting in

| name | coalesce |
| --- | --- |
| STUDIO | *NULL* |
| ONE BEDROOM | *NULL* |

so, not only is the default value unable to populate, leaving the values NULL in an attribute that is defined as NOT NULL, but the example SELECT statements above all behave in exactly the same way when run against the new table.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: What does `pg_dump` of the table produce?

Comment: If I copy out to a csv it looks like it's doing nulls as ,"", instead of the usual ,, - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: community_id,year,week,number,name,description,beds,baths
55bd981ff-ad4d-4e80-b70e-7d372761e840,2022,1,2,STUDIO,"",0,1.00
5bd981ff-ad4d-4e80-b70e-7d372761e840,2022,1,3,STUDIO,"",0,1.00
5bd981ff-ad4d-4e80-b70e-7d372761e840,2022,1,5,STUDIO,"",0,1.00
5bd981ff-ad4d-4e80-b70e-7d372761e840,2022,1,6,STUDIO,"",0,1.00

Comment: From the CSV, those are clearly empty strings, not NULLs.  I suspect the tool you are using to extract data and format it for presentation is doing something naughty with empty strings.  Is an Oracle-focuses tool?

Comment: If you use [pg_dump to output the data as insert statements](https://carlosbecker.com/posts/dump-postgres-table-inserts/), what does it show for the values of the `description` field, `null` or `''`?

Comment: What happens if you do `select length(description);`? If you get `0` then you have empty strings. If you get `NULL` then you have `NULL` values. I'm betting on empty strings. In `STUDIO  NULL` are you just saying 'NULL' because you don't see a value?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver and jjanes, yes it definitely appears to be empty strings. It's bizarre, because in my query tool (Azure Data Studio) the values still show as NULL, rather than just blank. So, to Adrian's question, it does show as NULL rather than my having written NULL into my examples.

Comment: @BIllJetzer and xehpuk, I'll do a pg_dump and get back to you - since it's on GCS I need to get some permissions set up with our admin dept. to be allowed to pg_dump anything

Comment: Seems to be a Azure Data Studio [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio-postgresql/issues/143). Word to the wise, use `psql` to confirm query behavior. `psql`  is written by the same folks that write the server code, so it is the best way to test whether something is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the source database is writing empty strings instead of proper NULLs. Adding `NULLIF(description, '')` before trying to COALESCE() solves the problem.

Thanks to everyone!